# Big int и int, mysql максимальная длина

Tags: mysql, база-данных, архитектура

какая максимальная длина символов может быть у int и big int?

Comment: У int и bigint нету символов. У их представления в десятичной форме - 9 и 19 соответственно, у unsigned 9 и 20.

Comment: google: "Mysql типы данных"

Comment: 32 значное число не смогу засунуть в big int?

Comment: Вам же сказали, bigint 20 десятичных цифр. 32 > 20. Большее в меньшее не влезает ну ни как. И еще раз обратите внимание на мой комментарий про google: "Mysql типы данных"  если бы вы не ленились и набрали это в гугле, то через 3 минуты бы уже знали, что вам нужен тип данных numeric с указанием нужного размера

Answer (score 2):

TINYINT
Очень малое целое число. Диапазон со знаком от -128 до 127. Диапазон без знака от 0 до 255.

SMALLINT
Малое целое число. Диапазон со знаком от -32768 до 32767. Диапазон без знака от 0 до 65535.

MEDIUMINT
Целое число среднего размера. Диапазон со знаком от -8388608 до 8388607. Диапазон без знака от 0 до 16777215.

INT
Целое число нормального размера. Диапазон со знаком от -2147483648 до 2147483647. Диапазон без знака от 0 до 4294967295.

BIGINT
Большое целое число. Диапазон со знаком от -9223372036854775808 до 9223372036854775807. Диапазон без знака от 0 до 18446744073709551615.